# Express js, how to match all routes, even sub routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am building a node js app that needs to return a 404 page for all routes except for the `/video` route.

```
app.get('/video/*', Video.show)
app.get('*', (req,res) => res.render('not_found'))
```

This works if the URL does not have subdirectories. 
The problem arises when someone enters a URL with subdirectories such as `/hello/subhello/`. This is not caught by my routes.

I already tried these options with no success:

```
app.get('/*', (req,res) => res.render('not_found'))
app.use((req,res) => res.render('not_found'))
```

Am I missing something ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

When i remove the code to set up handlebars the routes are followed as expected.

This is the handlebars set up code:

```
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    extname:'.hbs',
    defaultLayout:'layout.hbs',
    layoutsDir: __dirname+ '/views'
  }))
  app.set('view engine', '.hbs')
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
```

Comment: You will have to do `app.use()` if you don't know what you are looking for. Then you can make your own logic using `req.url` or some of it's parts. `req.method` will tell you if it's `GET`, `POST`, etc.

Comment: I have already tried that. It still does not catch it. even if I just say `app.use((req,res) => res.redirect('not_found'))`

Comment: if you put a console log in that function, are you ever getting there? If not, you must be redirecting or responding before it gets there. Also, is `not_found` the name of a view you have? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: It would help if you posted a small reproduction script

Comment: I am using handlebars as an engine. non_found is one of the views i can render. It works fine whenever I use it in the `/video/*` route. If the video requested is not there i render not found and that works. Also, i tried putting a console.log and it prints the content multiple times like it was redirected there many times. why would that be? I am only rendering a partial.

Comment: @aaaaaa I am creating the small script. Ill edit the question soon

Comment: everything works fine when I remove the handlebars code. It seems like handlebars interfere with my routes. I have edited my question with the handlebars set up code.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a working demo:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
  extname:'.hbs',
  defaultLayout:'layout.hbs',
  layoutsDir: __dirname+ '/views'
}))

app.set('view engine', '.hbs')
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')

app.get(['/videos', '/videos/*'], function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.status(404).send('Not found')
})

app.listen(1233, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 1233!');
});
```

Whether you access **localhost:1233/videos** or **localhost:1233/videos/*** you will get a Hello World response. If you go somewhere else, you get the not found.

EDIT:
Added handlebars code, same as you have. Still works as expected.

Comment: Thanks! I had a similar demo done and it works fine. I am guessing it is something else with the set up of handlebars that is causing this issue

Comment: It's important the order in which you put the middlewares. In this demo is evident, but in larger apps it might be troublesome.

Comment: Ok, if I remove the code to set up handlebars everything works as expected. i'll edit my question to reflect that